# template function taking argument function pointer to a class method

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I have a simple class as mentioned below.

```
typedef mytype int;
typedef mytype2 float;

class A {
     .
     .
     void run (mytype t) { .... do something with t ..... }
     .
     .
}
```

I have another class where I have created a template function (to make it independent of class A) which is supposed to take function pointer to (i.e class A method run) along with its parameter.

```
class B {
     .
     template< // how it should be defined >
             void myfunction ( // how parameters will be passed ) { }
```

The driver should be something like

```
      A a
      B b
      C c
      b.myfunction(&A::run, mytype);     // Or how it should be called
      b.myfunction(&B::run, mytype2);    // - do -
```

Ideas / Code / Reason ?

Regards,
Farrukh Arshad.

Answer (score 3):

```
class B {
    template <typename T>
    void myfunction(void (T::*func)(mytype), mytype val) {
        (some_instance_of_T.*func)(val); // or whatever implementation you want
    }
};
```

The parameter `func` is defined as a pointer to a non-static member function of `T`, taking `mytype` and returning `void`.

You need to get `some_instance_of_T` from somewhere. What instance of `A` do you want `myfunction` to call `func` on? If it's the caller's object `a`, then either `myfunction` needs another parameter to supply `a`, or else use `bind` as Alex says, and define:

```
class B {
    template <typename Functor>
    void myfunction(Functor f, mytype val) {
        f(val); // or whatever implementation you want
    }
};
```

or if you want to constrain the type of what the user passes in:

```
class B {
    void myfunction(std::function<void(mytype)> f, mytype val) {
        f(val); // or whatever implementation you want
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind);

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
b.myfunction(std::bind(&A::run, a, _1), mytype);
```

Define B as follows

```
class B {
     .
     template<typename Callable, typename Arg>
             void myfunction (Callable fn, Arg a) {fn(a); }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question well, but you may want to try using `std::function` and `std::bind`, e.g.:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void run(int n)
    {
        std::cout << "A::run(" << n << ")" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B
{
    typedef std::function< void( int ) > function_type;

    void driver(function_type f, int value)
    {
        std::cout << "B::driver() is calling:" << std::endl;
        f( value );
    }
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    b.driver( 
        std::bind<void>(&A::run, &a, std::placeholders::_1), 
        10
    );
}
```

Output:

> B::driver() is calling:
>
> A::run(10)